# What is the average global income in 2022?

Tags: inequality

2021 is also fine but I could only find old data. Median income may also be of value but I do not really believe in this metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2022 is still ongoing, hence it is impossible to say now what is the global average income in 2022.

For 2021, the average income according to [World Bank](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD) data on GDP per capita was: \$12262.9 measured in current dollars.

Comment: I think GDP/capita won't do for the task

Comment: @samuelnihoul you asked for average income. GDP by definition is sum of all incomes and dividing it by number of people means it’s average income.

Comment: Oh I thought GDP was more related to production than wages

Comment: @samuelnihoul production is measured as the sum of all incomes in the economy also income is not just wage but also corporate income and other forms of income